# Determine Ubuntu version

Tags: ubuntu

The latest server versions are listed around 6-9 and my server says...

```
Linux ikeyprod 2.6.28-11-server #42-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 17 02:48:10 UTC 2009 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Am I really running 2.6?

Comment: You got 4 answers, all with 1 minute time difference. But: Googling for exactly the same words that you used for your title would have yielded the result even faster :-)

Comment: @chris_l, yeah but i don't get reputation points for people using google ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the **kernel version**, a single component of the Ubuntu distribution (but an important one). The best tool at your disposal for this would be `lsb_release -a`, which will give you the distribution name, version, and I think the codename.

Answer (score 1):

You are running the 2.6 version of the linux kernel.

The best way to determine which release you are running is to either check the `/etc/issue` file (which can be modified by an admin.

The more portable way to do this is to use the command: `lsb_release -a`

Answer (score 1):

You're running a 2.6 kernel. But that says nothing about your Ubuntu version. Use `cat /etc/lsb-release` instead. Alternatively: `cat /etc/issue`.

Answer (score 0):

Try uname -a

Check out the man page for more info...

NAME
       uname − print system information

SYNOPSIS
       uname [OPTION]...

DESCRIPTION
       Print certain system information.  With no OPTION, same as −s.

```
   −a, −−all
          print  all  information,  in the following order, except omit −p
          and −i if unknown:
```

Comment: The output in the question looks like it came from `uname -a`

Answer (score 0):

Over several different Linux distributions, I have found that using

```
 cat /etc/*release
```

will help me identify the Linux dialect, and its release.  I know that this works for Redhat, Centos, Fedora, SuSE, and Ubuntu....probably most likely Debian and OpenSuSE as well.